# Sparql: How to retrieve an arbitrary number of values of the same property?

Tags: sparql

Given a subject with multiple occurrences of the same property, is it possible to retrieve all the objects/values they point to, without specifying in advance their number?

This question resembles this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919742/using-sparql-to-locate-a-subject-with-multiple-occurrences-of-same-property).

Example data (taken from link above):

```
@prefix example: <http://example.org/> .
example:subject1 example:property example:object1 .
example:subject1 example:property example:object2 .
example:subject1 example:property example:object3 .
...
```

It is possible to get a defined number of objects via:

```
select ?subject ?object1/2/n 
where {?subject example:property ?object1, ?object2 .}
filter( ?object1 != ?object2 ).
```

But how to do if we do not know the number of occurrences of the property in advance? (besides programmatically). Thank you.

Comment: Do you need just `SELECT DISTINCT ?object WHERE {?subject example:property ?object}` ?!

Comment: Yes. Sorry the query was not complete, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you are a bit confused by the [Turtle syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#object-lists).

In fact,

```sql
SELECT ?object1
   WHERE {
   ?subject example:property ?object1, ?object2 .
   FILTER ( ?object1 != ?object2 ).
   }
```

is just a syntactic sugar for:

```sql
SELECT ?object1
   WHERE {
   ?subject example:property ?object1 .
   ?subject example:property ?object2 .
   FILTER ( ?object1 != ?object2 ).
   }
```

This pattern matches all the triples which are different from each other only by their objects.
I suppose, "a subject with multiple occurrences of the same property" (from your question) means "there exist different objects for the same subject and the same property".

The pattern is symmetric, i.e. if `:object1` is bound to `?object1` in a result, then `:object1` will be bound to `?object2` in another result. It doesn't matter for this pattern whether any third triple with different object `:object3` exists, but if it exists, `:object3` will be bound to `?object1` in yet another result.

You can try also something like this for better understanding:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?object1
   WHERE {
   ?subject example:property ?object1 .
   FILTER EXISTS {
      ?subject example:property ?object2 .
      FILTER ( ?object1 != ?object2 )
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I exactly meant "there exist different objects for the same subject and the same property". I understand the syntactic sugar but did not know/realize that the filtered pattern could catch all different objects by only forcing 2 triples to be different. If I understand well: whatever triple which matches the subject and the property and has a different object from another previous matching triple will be returned (this is actually the very essence of patterns, they fit multiple cases (!)). Thanks, now it's clearer!