# How to select all items of OWLList in original order?

Tags: sparql, owl

I was wondering, how to select all list ([OWLList based structure](https://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2006/submissions/abstracts/7.1_Drummond_listsInProtegeOWL.pdf)) items in the order they are presented in OWLList structure using SPARQL.

Let's consider the example from the paper:

```
OWLList ANDhasContents SOME Ser AND
   hasNext SOME ( OWLList ANDhasContents SOME Gly AND
       hasNext SOME (OWLList ANDhasContents SOME Lys AND
           hasNext SOME EmptyList))
```

This structure describes the list (Ser, Gly, Lys). So then one can ask the question "give me the original sequence" and the answer must be (Ser, Gly, Lys).

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530689

Comment: The only way in SPARQL to process nested complex OWL constructs is by means of property paths.

Comment: @StanislavKralin your link just provides the common way of parsing RDF collections which are used in e.g. `owl:intersectionOf` constructs. That won't be enough here given that it is some OWL way of modelling lists. Clearly, the authors never had in mind that it should be processed by SPARQL. I'm not saying it's impossible, but at least the property paths are more complex