# How to maintain order while retrieving the data in sparql

Tags: sparql, amazon-neptune, rdf4j

Is there a way to ensure the order during the retrieval in sparql?

Say I want to store `List<Literals>`(order important) as an object

`{:subj :pred 'o1'. :subj :pred 'o2'. :subj :pred 'o3'}`

How can I insert the above data such that when I perform `select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o}` the order shouldn't change?

Do sparql always preserve the insertion data order when retrieved?

In the above example, I used literals as an example. Is there a way of preserving the order of IRIs as well?

I have seen sparql documentation on `RDF.Seq`, But I didn't understand exactly how to use that. Please provide some simple insert and select queries for ensuring order or share any relevant resources.

Comment: if you add `List<Literals>` - whatever this is - as an object, this is supposed to be a container like `rdf:Seq` or `rdf:List` - but then you have to resolve this container sturcture - made of many triples - in you SPARQL query. `select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o}` would just return a single row where some bnode is bound to variable `?o` and  represents the container/list. So there is no order between RDF triples given that an RDF dataset is a **set** of RDF triples.

Comment: If we mentioned a node as type `RDF.Seq` and inserted the node in graph store, Is the type just for representational purpose or does anything specific happens(i.e, order preservation) while retrieving or doing any operations? @UninformedUser

Answer (score 3):

If you need to preserve order you can represent the list as an RDF Collection. If you have a list of strings, e.g.:

```java
 List<String> objects = Arrays.asList("o1", "o2", "o3");
```

representing it as an RDF collection would look something like this (in Turtle syntax):

```java
_:node a rdf:List;
       rdf:first "o1" ;
       rdf:rest [ 
          rdf:first "o2";
          rdf:rest [
             rdf:first "o3";
             rdf:rest rdf:nil .
          ]
       ].
```

That may look cumbersome, but the RDF4J libraries offer some [RDF Collection utilities](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/model/#rdf-collections) to make handling this easier from code. To transform your Java list to an RDF Collection, you can do something like this:

```java
// starting node of the RDF collection
Resource head = valueFactory.createBNode();
// convert our list and add it to a newly-created Model
Model collection = RDFCollections.asRDF(objects, head, new LinkedHashModel());
```

Here, `collection` is just an RDF model (a set of RDF statements) that you can add to your triplestore like any other RDF data (see [the RDF4J docs](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/repository/#working-with-models-collections-and-iterations) for some further tips on how to work with collections when storing and retrieving from a repository).

To convert a RDF collection back to a Java list (preserving order):

```java
List<Value> values = RDFCollections.asValues(collection, head, new ArrayList<Value>());
```

Or if you want them back as a list of string objects again:

```java
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
RDFCollections.consumeValues(collection, head, v -> values.add(v.stringValue()));
```

**Edit** it is also possible to retrieve such RDF collection items in order using SPARQL 1.1, though it is not straightforward. See [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523804/is-it-possible-to-get-the-position-of-an-element-in-an-rdf-collection-in-sparql) for a good solution.

All that being said though, it's probably a good idea to stop and think if you actually *need* to store things in a fixed order. RDF is by its nature unordered, and while RDF Collection modelling provide a mechanism, it's not efficient to store everything as collections.

In most common cases, the order is not really part of the actual data model, but is a presentation issue. In those cases, you can most of the time use a SPARQL query with an `ORDER BY` clause instead, to sort the query results.

Comment: you should also mention how to access those RDF collections via SPARQL. That's what the TO was also asking and as we now is sometimes weird - RDF4J might have some custom SPARQL function for it, otherwise one would have to sue SPARQL property paths I think

Comment: Good point. Added a link to a question that is specifically about that.

Answer (score 2):

The use-case does not seem to fit well with the RDF model. Since RDF describes a graph, order of its edges is not important.

Having this said, one simple solution to your particular use-case might be e.g. using a reified node with two extra RDF properties `:order` and `:value` :

**RDF:**

```
:subj :pred [:order 1; :value 'o1']. 
:subj :pred [:order 2; :value 'o2']. 
:subj :pred [:order 3; :value 'o3'].
```

**SPARQL:**

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o {
  ?s ?p [:order ?order; :value ?o]
} ORDER BY ?order
```

Comment: If we mentioned a node as type `RDF.Seq` and inserted the node in graph store, Is the type just for representational purpose or does anything specific happens(i.e, order preservation) while retrieving or doing any operations? @Petr Křemen

Comment: Marking a node as a RDF sequence only prescribes that the node will have container membership functions. So no special handling AFAIK.