# How can in iterate over a list in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have an RDF document which contains:

```
:booklist :contains ( :Book1 :Book2 :Book3 ) .
```

And I want to create a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query to create an RDF document which contains:

```
:Book1 :order 1 .
:Book2 :order 2 .
:Book3 :order 3 .
```

I know how to loop over the RDF List but don't know how get the iteration on `order` numbers. E.g. this gives me the list but not the order number.

````
CONSTRUCT {
   ?book :order 1 
} WHERE {
   ?collection :contains/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?book .
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

A solution has been provided by Labra in this answer [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523804/is-it-possible-to-get-the-position-of-an-element-in-an-rdf-collection-in-sparql)

The trick can be summarised as follows. Input data:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/#> 

:booklist :contains ( :Book1 :Book2 :Book3 ) .
```

SPARQL:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/#> 

CONSTRUCT {
    ?part :order ?position .
} WHERE {
   SELECT ?part (count(?mid) - 1 AS ?position) WHERE {
                ?thing :contains/rdf:rest* ?mid .
                ?mid rdf:rest* ?node .
                ?node rdf:first ?part .
            } GROUP BY ?node ?part
}
```

which results in:

```
<http://example.org/#Book1> <http://example.org/#order> 0.
<http://example.org/#Book2> <http://example.org/#order> 1.
<http://example.org/#Book3> <http://example.org/#order> 2.
```

It is still an open question for me how to go how to go in the opposite direction.