# Get weighted shortest path in an Openlink Virtuoso Knowledge Graph

Tags: sparql, shortest-path, virtuoso

## Context

Given a certain KG with the following structure

```
<distanceTo:1> <weight>              3               .
<distanceTo:1> <weight>              4               .

<a>            <distance_with_weight> <distanceTo:1> .
<distanceTo:1> <goes_to>              <b>            .
<b>            <distance_with_weight> <distanceTo:2> .
<distanceTo:2> <goes_to>              <c>            .
```

I'd say that there is a path between `a` and `c` with a weight of `3 + 4 = 7`.

## Question

**Is there a way to calculate weighted shortest path using SPARQL or SPARQL-BI?**

I know there's the `TRANSITIVE` and `T_SHORTEST` clauses, but as far as I understand they only work with simple edges (with no weights).

I understand that I can enumerate all the paths and take the minimum sum of weights, but that'd be undesirable since, in this context, the SSSP Dijkstra algorithm could be way faster.

## What I have so far

```
SELECT ?t, total_weight
WHERE {
  <a> <distance_with_weight>/<goes_to>* ?t.
  # here I need the sum of the weights involved so that I can get the minimum later.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know SPARQL-BI, so maybe there is a solution to the general problem, but a pure SPARQL solution can work if your graph is a tree, that is, if there is a unique path that goes from one point to another. This solution is partly inspired by [Joshua Taylor's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530689/1260887):

```sql
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?destination (SUM(?weight) AS ?total_weight) WHERE { 
  <a> (<distance_with_weight>/<goes_to>)*/<distance_with_weight> ?d .
  ?d <weight> ?weight .
  ?d <goes_to>/(<distance_with_weight>/<goes_to>)* ?destination .
}
GROUP BY ?destination
```

When the graph is not a tree (or forest), there can be several paths between 2 points, so that the query will add all the weights of all the paths. Cycles are problematic too but not more than multiple paths. Finally, the data needs to be complete, with a weight assigned to all `<distanceTo:i>` nodes, and for each pair (`<a>`,`<b>`), there must be a distinct `<distanceTo:i>` node.